# How to find out where systemwide keybindings come from, and remove them?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I switched my keyboard layout to Polish, in which Alt_R is used to generate various non-Latin letters. Some of them are working, and some aren't:

- `Alt_R-l` generates "ł", as it should
- `Alt_R-c` should generate "ć" but instead starts Chromium
- several other Alt_R key combinations also start various programs, or move the current window down by a small distance, or do nothing

Where are those functions coming from? There's nothing about it in my Settings->Keyboard dialog, or in ~/.Xmodmap - what are other places where systemwide keyboard shortcuts or other keyboard modifications might be defined? Is there an exhaustive list?

Better yet, is there a way to find out what application/system is reacting to a key combination like `Alt_R-c` so that I can then figure out where it keeps its keybindings?

This is on Xubuntu 20.04.3.

Comment: Check the file `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml`.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! It doesn't seem to have anything relevant, but it does have a lot of keybindings that might be important next time I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a keysym **`XF86LogGrabInfo`** which when pressed causes the X Server to print information about all the **grabs** in its log file (usually `/var/log/Xorg.$DISPLAY.log`). If you have `xdotool` installed, you can trigger that key with a command like

```
xdotool key XF86LogGrabInfo
```

From there you could identify the culprit X11 client. For instance, to determine which X11 client is messing with the "Space" key, I first get the keycode bound to the `space` keysym:

```
$ xkbcomp $DISPLAY - | grep SPCE
    <SPCE> = 65;
    key <SPCE> {         [           space ] };
```

(you can also use `xev` + press `Space` for that), then I search for it through `Xorg.$DISPLAY.log`:

```
$ awk '/registered grabs of client/{c=$0}/detail 65/{if(c)print c; c=""; print}' /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[452727.209]   Printing all registered grabs of client pid 32055 openbox --config-file /home/pi/.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml
[452727.220]     detail 65 (mask 0), modifiersDetail 8 (mask 0)
[452727.220]     detail 65 (mask 0), modifiersDetail 24 (mask 0)
[452727.220]     detail 65 (mask 0), modifiersDetail 10 (mask 0)
[452727.220]     detail 65 (mask 0), modifiersDetail 26 (mask 0)
[452727.241]     detail 65 (mask 0), modifiersDetail 12 (mask 0)
[452727.241]     detail 65 (mask 0), modifiersDetail 28 (mask 0)
[452727.241]     detail 65 (mask 0), modifiersDetail 14 (mask 0)
[452727.241]     detail 65 (mask 0), modifiersDetail 30 (mask 0)
```

`modifiersDetail 8` is `Mod1Mask` aka `Alt`, etc.

So it's `openbox` which is stealing the `Alt-Space` key combo.

---

Notice that the pids and command lines of the clients are not always accurate; they're those of the processes who **connected** to the Xorg unix domain socket, which may no longer exist if they forked in the meanwhile and their children inherited the socket file descriptor (That's a general problem with the naive misuse of `SO_PEERCRED` "authentification", which is quite a long story ;-))